# .net mvc 4 application - call from ajax to a function in controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm creating mvc 4 application where I call a function in controller from a js file using ajax.

When I call the function from ajax, its calling the respective function properly. But neither success nor error function is not firing . Could someone help me out to correct my mistake?

I would like to read the data from database convert it to json format and write it into a .js file and thereafter success function to be fired off. Help me to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Here is my Code.

```
  $.ajax({
        //url: '@Url.Action("getJsonData","Home")',
        url: "Home/getJsonHugeData1",
        //data: "{}",
        type: "GET",
        //contentType: 'application/json',
        //dataType: "json",
        success: function () {
            alert();
            alert('success getJsonHugeData');
            loaddata(data);
        },
        error:function(){
            alert('error');
        }
    });
```

Controller:

```
public JsonResult getJsonHugeData()
    {
        var users = GetUsersHugeData();
        string json = "var dataSource=";
        json += JsonConvert.SerializeObject(users.ToArray());
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(Server.MapPath("/Scripts/NewData.js"), json);
        return Json(users, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);


    }


 private List<UserModel> GetUsersHugeData()
    {
        var usersList = new List<UserModel>();
        UserModel user;

        List<dummyData> data = new List<dummyData>();

        using (Database1Entities dataEntity = new Database1Entities())
        {
            data = dataEntity.dummyDatas.ToList();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < data.Count; i++)
        {
            user = new UserModel
            {
                ID = data[i].Id,
                ProductName = data[i].ProductName,
                Revenue = data[i].Revenue,
                InYear = data[i].InYear.Year
            };
            usersList.Add(user);
        }
     }
```

Comment: What do you mean _write it into a .js file_? What would be the point - all your writing is data, not javascript - there is nothing to execute?

Comment: Try `success: function (data) {.....`

Comment: Thanks for your response.                                                              Actually I'll getting result as follows     "ID":1,"ProductName":"ProductA","Revenue":30000,"InYear":2016                             which is in the json format. I want this to be written in a file. Actually I got it written in the file. But success function in ajax is not firing on. Thats the problem

Comment: My comment was in relation to your file extension. `.js` is a javascrit file. It should be a `.json` file. What error are you getting in the browser console.

Comment: Yeah. exactly. I'm not getting any error message or success message. It just provides me a download dialog box and once after it is downloaded, application ends up.

Comment: What do you mean a _download dialog box_? There is nothing in the code you have shown that would do that (your returning a `JsonResult` , not a `FileResult`

Comment: Yes I agree with you @Stephen. When I run the application, I'm getting a json file downloaded. And after that application stops from executing. It doesn't fire the success or error function is my problem.

Comment: The problem is within your View. Your submit button is probably within a form tag. And your $.ajax({... is not being called. Insert a snippet from your view in the question.
Verfiy this by adding an alert('ajax') on top in your $.ajax({.. method.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your browser will block the file downloaded via ajax, this is because JavaScript cannot interact with disk. If you want to get this working, you will have to do so using a form post.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "DownloadForm" }))
{
    ... form data would be here if you had any...
    <button type="submit">Download</button>
}
```

You would then return a FileStreamResult with the contents of the file to be downloaded.

```
public ActionResult Action(FormModel model)
{
    // Do work to get data for file and then return your file result to the browser.
    return new FileStreamResult(new MemoryStream(fileData), "text/csv") // set the document type that is valid for your file
    {
        FileDownloadName = "users.csv"
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran all of your code except for the following since you didn't provide the UserModel and dummydata classes in your question:

```
private List<UserModel> GetUsersHugeData()
{
    var usersList = new List<UserModel>();
    UserModel user;

    List<dummyData> data = new List<dummyData>();

    using (Database1Entities dataEntity = new Database1Entities())
    {
        data = dataEntity.dummyDatas.ToList();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < data.Count; i++)
    {
        user = new UserModel
        {
            ID = data[i].Id,
            ProductName = data[i].ProductName,
            Revenue = data[i].Revenue,
            InYear = data[i].InYear.Year
        };
        usersList.Add(user);
    }
 }
```

The end result was that you had a typo in your ajax 'url' parameter. Also, if you are going to check for errors, set your function to

```
function(jqxhr, status, error) {
    alert(error);
}
```

to check the error being thrown.